# Package Listings Error: File B(.tex) not found

Tags: listings

I'm trying to insert a Visual Basic Code Snippet into my latex document.
I've got listings package intalled and it works for C++ code.
But when I try to use the following command it shows the error (Package Listings Error: File B(.tex) not found).

```
\small 
\singlespace
\lstinputlisting[frame=single,title={VarGlob.bas},language=[Visual]Basic)]{codigo/VarGlob.vb}
\normalsize 
\onehalfspace
```

Can someone help me figuring this out please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the way LaTeX handles optional arguments, is that when a `[` is seen after a macro name, it considers everything from that `[` to the first `]` it sees in the same brace level as the optional argument. Hence, when you have `language=[Visual]Basic`, LaTeX sees the `]` after `Visual` as the end of the optional argument. `\lstinputlisting` has one mandatory argument, so LaTeX then grabs the next token it finds, the `B` in `Basic` and that becomes the mandatory argument.

This explains the error you get -- `B` is read as the filename, and `listings` seems to have `.tex` as a default extension (based on the error message).

Hence, you have to do `language={[Visual]Basic}`, with an extra set of braces to not have that `]` interpreted as the end of the optional argument.

Further, instead of the `\small\singlespace`/`\normalsize\onehalfspace`, I would add the `\small\singlespace` to the `basicstyle` of the `listing`. Note that if you have a `\lstset` in the preamble to set the general style, I would add it there instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text, no need to include it in your actual document

\begin{document}
\onehalfspace
\lipsum[1]
\lstinputlisting[
  basicstyle=\small\singlespace,
  frame=single,
  title={VarGlob.bas},
  language={[Visual]Basic}
]{codigo/VarGlob.vb}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```